# Unable to update Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google from version 2.0.0 to 4.0.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to implement external authentication in my Web-api project by following this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsRyvWvo4EI&t=609s

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions() { 
                ClientId = "",
                ClientSecret=""

});
```

The code above could not find GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions class.. searching through the problem it appears that my microsoft.owin.security.google package is not updated. When i try to update it using NuGet, it fails to download the package showing the following error:

[NuGet Error while downloading the Microsoft.Owin.Security.Goolge 4.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSHV1.png)

How do i update the package and make the google authentication work

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your project Target Framework to at least `.Net Framework 4.5.1`